# Datatables - showing/hiding with select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I currently have 2 working datatables and a select box. Currently, they both show up on page load, and then if I select one from the select box it shows that one and hides the other. The select box works great from there, but I'd like to show just one table on page load by default, rather than both.

Here is the datatable script with select box code:

```
<select name='tables' id='select-tables'>
<option value="mytable">Survey Test Table</option>
<option value="mytableSurvey">Survey Only</option>
</select>
</br>

<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mytable').DataTable();
$('#mytableSurvey').DataTable();
$('.dataTable').wrap('<div class="dataTables_scroll" />');

// select change event
$(document).on('change' , '#select-tables', function(){
 var table = $(this).val();
 $('#' + table +'_wrapper').show();
 $('[id$="_wrapper"]').not('#' + table +'_wrapper').hide();
}).change();
});
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Obviously, my table IDs are mytable and mytableSurvey so I won't post any of my actual table code, as everything necessary is in the datatable script here.

Everything here works, I'm just hoping to find an addition to this code that will only show 'mytable' on page load.

Comment: what is #mytable and #mytableSurvey?

Comment: The ids of my two tables

Comment: Remove `.change()` here `$('[id$="_wrapper"]').not('#' + table+'_wrapper').hide();}).change()` and try `$('[id$="_wrapper"]').not('#'+ table +'_wrapper').hide();});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable').DataTable();
    $('#mytableSurvey').DataTable();

    $(document).on('change' , '#select-tables', function(){
 var table = $(this).val();
 $('#' + table +'_wrapper').show();
 $('[id$="_wrapper"]').not('#' + table +'_wrapper').hide();
});
$("#select-tables").trigger("change");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/2012/)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to select a option by default on page load. Or adding "selected" to html of any one option (best way).

**Sample Javascript** :-

```
document.getElementById('select-tables').getElementsByTagName('option')[0].selected = 'selected'
```

Adding this to your $(document).ready() function might do this for you.